# Having trouble with writing data to the Django SQL Lite DB

Tags: python, django, database

Hey guys I'm trying to build a basic auction site to learn Python and I have an issue with writing data to the db using Django (SQL Lite). I used "python manage.py inspectdb" and found that the database is updated and built fine with all 5 fields I'm looking to use.

I am building a Watchlist feature and when the user clicks "Add to Watchlist", it's supposed to add it to that users watchlist - however it's not adding any data - even when I hard code the data in like I have it now.

I included the code for the new Post option, which I wrote and is working just fine even though it's very similar to the Watchlist feature.  I just can't figure out why it's not working.

Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def watchlist(request, username):
if request.method == "POST":
    new = Watchlist.objects.create(username = username, title = "Monkey", description = "Eats bananas", price = 300, category = "Animals")
    new.save()
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html")
else:
    query = Watchlist.objects.all()
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", { "queries": query })
```

watchlist.html:

```
   % block body %}
    <h2>Watch List</h2>
<ul>

    {% for query in queries %}
            <li><a href="/watchlist/{{query.user}}">{{ query.title }} - {{ query.description }} - ${{ query.price }} - {{ query.category }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}  
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Turns out I didn't have a form in my html page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not solve the problem, but one thing you might want to do is move the `query = Watchlist.objects.all()` line and subsequent return out of the "else" block. Currently the query results are never being passed to the template after a POST call. Something more like:

```
def watchlist(request, username):
  if request.method == "POST":
    new = Watchlist.objects.create(username = username, title = "Monkey", description = "Eats bananas", price = 300, category = "Animals")
    new.save()

  query = Watchlist.objects.all()
  return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", { "queries": query })
```

Comment: awesome so it works as soon as i get rid of the if statement. However, now I have an issue: if the user clicks on the Watchlist to view the watchlist, they end up adding an entry as well. Since they are both GETs, how would I separate the two?

Comment: hmm, that's odd. When you say you got rid of the if statement, do you mean you removed both the if and else? If so I might recommend keeping the if and changing the indentation like above.

Comment: I have it just like you have it above.  Now I get an error saying "The view auctions.views.watchlist didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `username`argument from your `views.py` file

In your html file add your for loop in a form tag

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token%}
    # your for loop
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Django view you are checking for an HTTP request, but your HTML code has no form, only a hyperlink. The hyperlink will perform a get method, not a post.
You can either change your HTML to a form or change your view to trigger the creation on a HTTP get.

Comment: awesome it works but now even when I click to view the Watchlist, it adds another entry. Since they are both GETS, how can I separate the two so a user can go view his watchlist and click add to watchlist to post to the watchlist?  Any ideas without having to drastically rewrite?

Comment: You could add an extra get parameter called 'action' that needs to be present for your code to create an entry. This is the least change. The best way would be to work with an HTTP post, which is also the most "correct". A post triggers change, a get returns data.